# How has the Chinese freight industry developed during last year?

Tags: supply-and-demand, international-trade, nonexpert, covid-19-crisis, china

The last year has been filled with so many unfamiliar circumstances such as Covid-19, and now with the rising tensions as well, I'm wondering how the Chinese freight industry is developing during these times.

I'm researching the attractiveness of expanding a freight forwarding business to China at this moment.
Any information is welcomed, thank you.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "developing"? How do you propose to measure this? Price? Revenue? Capacity?

Comment: As in the changes in freight forwarding dynamics based on general trends and developments, like PESTLE macro factors. Has political unrest disturbed the Chinese freight forwarding industry? How have the changes in the Chinese economy affected their freight forwarding situation? Is the Chinese freight forwarding industry easily accessible on a social-cultural level, etc. They are very broad questions, but I'd love any general information on it from someone who might work in a field related to this subject.